# How to make the bot respond to users response when a keyword is triggered?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to create a command, where the user responds after using the command and the bot responds again back to the user depending on the response. The code is in a cog, which makes this even harder to me. Bot responses are in Finnish but they don't matter in this case. Here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord import message
from discord.ext import commands
import random

randomnumber = random.randint(0,100)
hintnumber = random.randint(0,100)

class highlow(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Aliprosessi (highlow) on käynnissä.')

    @commands.command(aliases=['hl'])
    async def highlow(self, message):
        await message.channel.send('Satunnainen luku on valittu väliltä ``0-100``.\n'
                    f'Vihjeesi on ``{hintnumber}``.'
                    'Vastaa kirjoittamalla ``high``,``low`` tai ``vihje``.')

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.id == self.client.user.id:
            return
        else:
            if 'high' in message.content:
                if randomnumber > hintnumber:
                    await message.channel.send(f'Satunnainen luku oli ``{randomnumber}``, joten voitit pelin!')
                else:
                    await message.channel.send(f'Satunnainen luku oli ``{randomnumber}``, joten hävisit pelin!')

            if 'low' in message.content:
                if randomnumber < hintnumber:
                    await message.channel.send(f'Satunnainen luku oli ``{randomnumber}``, joten voitit pelin!')
                else:
                    await message.channel.send(f'Satunnainen luku oli ``{randomnumber}``, joten hävisit pelin!')

            if 'vihje' in message.content:
                if randomnumber == hintnumber:
                    await message.channel.send(f'Satunnainen luku oli ``{randomnumber}``, joten voitit pelin!')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(highlow(client))
```

This does not give me any errors. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I made the whole thing an event and even made it as simple as possible by making it as similar to the docs example as I could, but the bot still doesn't respond. Code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content.startswith('.highlow') and message.author != self.client.user:
            channel = message.channel
            await channel.send('Satunnainen luku on valittu väliltä ``0-100``.\n'
                                f'Vihjeesi on ``{hintnumber}``.'
                                'Vastaa kirjoittamalla ``high``,``low`` tai ``vihje``.')

            def check(message):
                return message.content == 'high' and message.channel == channel

            msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
            await channel.send(f'Satunnainen luku oli ``{randomnumber}``, joten voitit pelin!'.format(msg))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should find your happiness with this : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for

It allows you to "wait" a certain time for a certain answer, instead of going through on_message. You can replace `@client.event` to `@Cog.listener()`